# Not able to copy multiple SPFieldLookupValue from one list to another

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am having a scenario where I am required to copy the SharePoint list items from one list to another it includes various types of fields such as text, lookup and people group.

I am trying to copy the look-up field from one list to another using the following piece of code but what it does is it copies only the last value in the loop into the other list column but I want all the entire set items copied from one list to another.

```
foreach (SPFieldLookupValue value in values)
{                         
     targetItem["Hiring_x0020_Manager"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(value.ToString());
}
```

Is there anyway to copy the entire set of items from one list to another separately.

Also is it possible to copy SP Column type of people and look-up from one list to another using a similar code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

> …but what it does is it copies only the last value in the loop…

You keep overwriting the value of the destination field. Hence yes, it behaves like that.

For lookup fields that have multiple values enabled, you have to construct a new `SPFieldLookupValueCollection` instance and assign it to the destination field. I assume your `values` variable is exactly of this type. There is an extensive example [in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookupvaluecollection.aspx).